# Ruby Scoping Can't pass class variable

Tags: ruby

```
class Scraper

def initialize(options = {}) do
  @options = options
end

def scrape
  Wombat.crawl do
    base_url @options[:base_url]
    path @options[:path]
    some_data css: @options[:css]
  end
end

end
```

Sample Usage:

```
sample = Scraper.new({base_url: "someurl.com", path:"/random", css: ".regular"})
sample.scrape
```

I can't seem to access @options in inside the scrape method. Its a scoping issue and can probably resolved by flat scoping but I can't seem to get around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The var should be accessible. Show us the usage of this code.

Comment: Maybe the block passed into `crawl` method is evaluated in other context than is defined.
Like in Savon:
https://github.com/savonrb/savon/blob/version2/lib/savon/block_interface.rb

Comment: i just add "raise @options.to_yaml" inside Wombat.crawl. It shows values inside def scrape, but not inside Wombat.crawl

Comment: sample usage: 

sample = Scraper.new({base_url: "someurl.com", path:"/random", css: ".regular"})
sample.scrape

Comment: @AceDimasuhid: what about `Wombat.crawl`?

Comment: Ahh. Its a gem: Wombat.

Comment: It is an instance variable. Not class variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, as Marek Lipka says, the context is modified by `instance_eval`. If that is the case, you cannot access instance variables of the `Scraper` instance, but can access local variables. Do this:

```
def scrape
  options = @options
  Wombat.crawl do
    base_url options[:base_url]
    path options[:path]
    some_data css: options[:css]
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like it: https://github.com/felipecsl/wombat/blob/master/lib/wombat/crawler.rb